# RxJava. Periodical server polling with rare extraordinal messages

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have server polling solution like this:

```
Observable
    .interval(UPDATE_PERIOD_SEC, UPDATE_PERIOD_SEC, 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.newThread())
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<NewMessagesCountModel>>() {})
    .retry()
    .distinct()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .compose(this.<NewMessagesCountModel>bindToLifecycle())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<NewMessagesCountModel>() {});
```

I want rarely update data immediately without waiting for next polling event. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can mix in a `PublishSubject` and call `onNext()` of it whenever you want to trigger the service call:

```
PublishSubject<Long> manual = PublishSubject.create();

Observable
.interval(UPDATE_PERIOD_SEC, UPDATE_PERIOD_SEC, 
    TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.newThread())
.mergeWith(manual.onBackpressureDrop().observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()))
.flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<NewMessagesCountModel>>() {})
.retry()
.distinct()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.compose(this.<NewMessagesCountModel>bindToLifecycle())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<NewMessagesCountModel>() {});

manual.onNext(-100L);
```

In addition, I believe there is no need to call `subscribeOn` because there are no side effects to be moved off the calling thread.

If you want to avoid a manual call to be too close to a periodic call, you can apply `debounce` before the `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make another observable without the interval without the interval operator.

```
Observable
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<NewMessagesCountModel>>() {})
    .retry()
    .distinct()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .compose(this.<NewMessagesCountModel>bindToLifecycle())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<NewMessagesCountModel>() {});
```